# Manipulation of numpy structured objects

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've read a .mat file with scipy.io:

```
data = scipy.io.loadmat(etc.)
```

The function returns a dictionary, and my Matlab structure array is stored in a Numpy structured array. So far, so good. One of my fields is called `repet1_F3`, and should contain a vector of floats. I've accessed the vector using:

```
repet1_F3= data['repet1_F3']
```

`repet1_F3` has a weird structure that I can't manipulate:

```
>>> repet1_F3
array(array([ 0.48856978,  0.74278461, 2.73300925,  2.72642893, 2.73684854,  2.74516561,  2.69143553]), dtype=object)
```

Am I doing something wrong? How could I convert this object into a standard numpy array?

Comment: What does this data look like in matlab?

Comment: And what is `data.shape`?

Answer (score 1):

`loadmat` tends to wrap MATLAB structures in `numpy` object arrays.

```
array(array([ 0.48856978,  0.74278461, 
 2.73300925,  2.72642893,  2.73684854,  2.74516561,  2.69143553]), dtype=object)
```

Looks like a 1 element array of dtype object; that element is itself a 1d float array.  The outer array probably has shape `()` (0d).

Try `repet1_F3.item()` or `repet1_F3([])`.  One of those should give the inner array.

Do you know the MATLAB structure that contains numbers like this?

correction - it should be `repet1_F3[()]`.

Comment: repet1_F3.item() worked, thank you. The Matlab structure is a structure array. Numbers displayed in Matlab have a 4 decimals precision, but they have more in python. Don't know why.

Comment: The 4 decimals is just a display setting; the actual values are 32 or 64 bit floats.

Comment: I think `repet1_F3([])` should be `repet1_F3[()]`

Comment: you are right - the indexing [] go outside, the empty tuple inside.  That's what happens when I don't have a live shell to test things in.